# Many similar activities in Android App against DRY principle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, dry

I'm new to Android App Development and to Kotlin. So, now I have an app (written with Kotlin) with 20 activities one go after another: Activity1 -> Activity2 -> ... -> Activity20.

They all have the same structure of XML files which differ only in image presented. They also have similar code. As there are 2 buttons in each activity (NEXT and BACK) they only differ in "nextActivity" and "previousActivity" (for example, NEXT button for Activity3 intents Activity4 and NEXT button for Activity5 intents Activity6 and so on).

At some point, it started to worry me, so I tried to write an open class:

```
open class everyActivity(pic: Int, nextActivity: Activity, prevActivity: Activity): AppCompatActivity() {

val pic = pic
val nextActivity = nextActivity
val prevActivity = prevActivity

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(pic)
}

fun nextClick(view: View) {
    val nextIntent = Intent(this, nextActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(nextIntent)
    this.finish()
}

fun backClick(view: View){
    val prevIntent = Intent(this, prevActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(prevIntent)
    this.finish()
}
}
```

Then I tried to inherit these similar activities, but I cannot pass Activity as an Argument for class (due to "Classifier 'Activity2' does not have companion object and so on"):

```
class Activity2 : everyActivity(R.layout.activity_02, Activity3, Activity1) {}
```

And, overall, such construction looks pretty strange. That's when I thought that I may not have to do it at all.

So, **final question**:

There's is DRY principle considering most programming. However, I want to know: is it actually convenient to have similar codes for activities in Android?

Comment: You shouldn't even need different Activities. You can make a single class and pass it information via Intent extras for it to decide which image to load, etc.

Comment: But Intent calls new Activity, so don't quite understand the idea of changing images.

Comment: You can add extras to the Intent before using it to start an Activity. Activities can inspect the extras of the Intent that launched them.

Comment: What I mean is, you can keep opening new instances of the same Activity class and use the Intent extras in the Activity to determine its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things possible to achieve the `DRY` principle. 
To achieve `DRY` principles you should ask yourself that I am breaking another Android rule such as `Single Activity Architecture` which is the more android specific rule.

It is a good thing you are taking care of such a principle but as per `Single Activity Architecture`, You have to try to keep minimal Activity in the android app.

In this situation, you can create function to change the image and can call that function in `nextClick()` and `backClick()`. This solution will help you to achieve the DRY principle as well `Single Activity Architecture`.Also, you will get better user experience.

So, you don't need to create 10 Activities to show 10 images but you can create functions like this:

```
nextClickFunction():

var currentNumber = 1
var iamge = R.drawable.image1
var listOfImages = mutableListOf(
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,   
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6,
        R.drawable.image7,
        R.drawable.image8,
        R.drawable.image9,
        R.drawable.image10,
    }

fun nextClick(){
    image = listOfImages[currentNumber]
    setImageIntoImageView(image)
}

fun backClick(){
    image = listOfImages[currentNumber - 1]
    setImageIntoImageView(image)
}

fun setImageIntoImageView(int image){
   // Set image into ImageView here
}
```

Let me know if it can help you. 
Thanks & Happy coding..!